# date in url, having / is converted to %2f when i go to next (2nd or 3rd etc) page of crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

i am passing date in querystring, makes a query to DB which use this date to return a dataset,   and than i simply bind this datatable to my report..evry thing ok..but when i press the   navigation button (next) it give the error (Load Report Failed) i guess its due to the dates   in the url converts to %2f.
can any one tell me the workaround for it...

my url is(which works fine as report loaded for first time)

```
http://localhost:8186/Report.aspx?RptType=1&fromdate=5/1/2012&todate=5/31/2012
```

when i click next, url becomes like

```
http://localhost:8186/Report.aspx?RptType=1&fromdate=5%2f1%2f2012&todate=5%2f31%2f2012
```

my code is :

```
 string fromdate = Request.QueryString.Get("fromdate");
 string todate = Request.QueryString.Get("todate");


Dataset ds = sbg_JobSeeker.GetJobSeakerDetailInfo(fromdate, todate);
ds.Tables[0].TableName = "sbg_JobSeeker";
            reportSource.ReportDocument.Load(path + "Applicants.rpt");
            reportSource.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: Or you could have called UrlDecode to translate the UrlEncoded text back to decoded text.

Answer (score 0):

i found it my self..:P i just send my querystring like

```
txtDateFrom.Text.Replace('/', '-') + "&todate=" + txtDateTo.Text.Replace('/', '-')
http://localhost:8186/Report.aspx?RptType=1&fromdate=5-1-2012&todate=5-31-2012
```

its woriking fine for me now..:)